# c# how to check if queue contains object property with a specific value?

Tags: c#, queue

I want to get Boolean value if queue contains object having particular value in the properties.

e.g)

```
public class Order
{
    public string orderType { get; set; }
    public string sCode { get; set; }  
    public int iNum { get; set; }
    ...omit... 
}
Queue<Order> queueSendOrder = new Queue<Order>();
```

Then, how to check if Queue contains or not if contains any object having  sCode="Code1", iNum=1?

Thank you.

Comment: Queue is data structure which is **not** supposed to be used for traversing through all its items. Even if you manage to do that - it doesn't make much sense. Why don't you just use an array?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev `Queue<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so it's perfectly reasonable to iterate over the contents.

Comment: @DavidG Still, checking whether a queue has something is not a usual thing to do... At least I've never done it.

Comment: @Sweeper True, but "unusual" doesn't mean you're not supposed to do it.

Comment: Why not just use the `IEnumerable` extension methods? You can do something like `queueSendOrder.Any(o => o.iNum == 1 && o.sCode == "Code1")` or `var matchingItems = queueSendOrder.Where(o => o.sCode == "Code1").ToList();`

Comment: It would be perfectly reasonable to check for the existence of a property within queue items to avoid enqueueing a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Linq [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.1) extension method, this is quite simple:

```
var containsCode1 = queueSendOrder.Any(o => o.sCode == "Code1");
var containsNum1 = queueSendOrder.Any(o => o.iNum == 1);
```

Or both:

```
var containsCode1AndNum1 = queueSendOrder.Any(o => 
    o.sCode == "Code1"
    && o.iNum == 1);
```

Side note: It's considered bad practice these days to use Hungarian notation to denote types. So `sCode` should really just be `Code` and `iNum` would be `Num` (though I would choose a better name than that)